# jPlayer with two playlists

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I want to have a jPlayer to play music and be able to select the song to play from 2 different playlists.

One list is in a dropdown within the player UI and it's working fine.

The second list is in a different part of the HTML and I need the player to change the music when the user clicks a song's name in this playlist too.

So basically what I need is the jPlayer instance to be able to listen for events in both playlists, is this possible?

Both playlists include the same tracks, so that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Just needed to include both playlists within the same container which is used in the cssSelectorAncestor option when initializing jPlayer.

Comment: can you please provide code how you solve it? I need that solution too

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain it's been a while since I wrote the solution for this and my memory is not perfect, I think you just need to create both lists in containers using the class defined in cssSelectorAncestor.
For example, I create the player with this JS code:

var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: '#jquery_jplayer_1',
    cssSelectorAncestor: '#profile'
},
json,
{
    solution: 'flash, html',
    supplied: 'mp3, m4a, oga',
    swfPath: '/swf'
});

And then the lists are different place within the container with id profile.

Hope this helps.